# How to compile php extension for PHP 5.3.6 with debug, TS

Tags: php, php-extension

I've tried to create some php extension.

For the first I compiled `php 5.3.6` with `--enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts`.
Then I ceated my extension and use standart procedure for it

```
phpize
./configure --with-EXTNAME
make
```

Then copy `extname.so` to my php extensions directory, and change `php.ini`

And when I try to use php from cli I got an error

```
Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,NTS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,debug
```

When I try

```
./configure --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts
```

For extension I got warning that these options are not recognized by configure script.

So, how can I compile my extension to use with PHP compiled with options that I describer above without recompiling php itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `./configure --with-php-config=/path/to/correct/php-config`.

The configure script is likely using another `php-config` (likely the centrally installed one).

Comment: Oh...
And where can find right php-config?
I guess it is near the php in the bin directory, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

in my server there are 2 phpize

```
  /usr/bin/php/phpize
  /usr/bin/php-zts/phpize
```

to make sure it compiled with Thread Safety instead using "phpize" do

```
/usr/bin/php-zts/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-zts/php-config
make
make install
```

Comment: Note only pick the correct phpize isn't enough: --with-php-config is required too.